# Mathematica: Code provided output few days ago, but in constant "running" status now

Tags: performance, caching, wolfram-mathematica

I solved for an equation where the output was 5 solutions for variable of interest. It took a while, but it ran yesterday. I tried to rerun the code today, with `ClearSystemCache[]` and `ClearGlobal` options but it seems to be "running" for the past 2 hours. I aborted and tried again, restarted my computer, cleared computer cache and tried again... no luck. When I numerically solve using `NDSolve` I can see it generates 5 solutions, just like the previous one. However, I want the analytical solution to work with, not numerical solutions. What could be causing this choking?

```
Eq1 = (1/(e1^2 ep^2))(-(((a1 ep f f1 fp R - e1 ep fp^2 m1 (h + R) + 
         ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp - a1 mp R) + Sqrt[
         ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
               e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
              e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
              a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)]) (ep^2 f1 (h + 
            R) (ab fp + a1 mp R) + 
         ep fp (a1 f f1 R - 
            e1 m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + 
               R)) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                 ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                 e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
                e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)))^4 (-ep^2 f1 (h + 
            R) (ab f f1 fp R - a1 f f1 mp R^2 + 
            ab e1 fp m1 mp (h + R) + 
            e1 m1 mp (2 fp - a1 mp) R (h + R)) - 
         ep fp (a1 f^2 f1^2 R^2 - e1 f f1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) R (h + R) + 
            e1^2 fp m1^2 mp (h + R)^2) + 
         e1 h m1 mp \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                  ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                  e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) -
                  e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                 a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
         f f1 R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                  ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                  e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) -
                  e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                 a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
         e1 m1 mp R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                  ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                  e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) -
                  e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                 a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)))^4 (fp + (1/(
         2 ep (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R)))(a1 ep f f1 fp R - 
           e1 ep fp^2 m1 (h + R) + 
           ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp - 
              a1 mp R) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 +
                    ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                   e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                  a1 f1 R (f fp + 
                    ep mp (h + 
                    R)))^2)))))/(512 a1^2 ep^9 f1^2 fp^6 mp^4 (h + 
         R)^9 (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R)^5 (a1 f f1 R - 
         e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R))^4)) - 
  e1^2 ep m1 (ep mp + (1/(
     2 a1 (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R)))(a1 ep f f1 fp R - 
       e1 ep fp^2 m1 (h + R) + ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp - a1 mp R) + 
       Sqrt[ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
             ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
             e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
            e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
            a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)]) - (1/(
     2 a1 (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
        ep f1 R)))(ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp + a1 mp R) + 
       ep fp (a1 f f1 R - e1 m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R)) + Sqrt[
       ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
             e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
            e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
            a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)])) (R - (-ep^2 f1 (h + 
           R) (ab f f1 fp R - a1 f f1 mp R^2 + 
           ab e1 fp m1 mp (h + R) + 
           e1 m1 mp (2 fp - a1 mp) R (h + R)) - 
        ep fp (a1 f^2 f1^2 R^2 - e1 f f1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) R (h + R) + 
           e1^2 fp m1^2 mp (h + R)^2) + 
        e1 h m1 mp Sqrt[
         ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
               e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
              e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
              a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)] + 
        f f1 R Sqrt[
         ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
               e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
              e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
              a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)] + 
        e1 m1 mp R Sqrt[
         ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
               e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
              e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
              a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)])/(2 ep^2 f1 mp (h + 
          R) (a1 f f1 R - 
          e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R))) - ((a1 ep f f1 fp R - 
          e1 ep fp^2 m1 (h + R) + ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp - a1 mp R) + 
          Sqrt[ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
               e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
               a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)]) (-ep^2 f1 (h + 
             R) (ab f f1 fp R - a1 f f1 mp R^2 + 
             ab e1 fp m1 mp (h + R) + 
             e1 m1 mp (2 fp - a1 mp) R (h + R)) - 
          ep fp (a1 f^2 f1^2 R^2 - e1 f f1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) R (h + R) +
              e1^2 fp m1^2 mp (h + R)^2) + 
          e1 h m1 mp \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                   ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                   e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                  a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
          f f1 R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                   ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                   e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                  a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
          e1 m1 mp R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                   ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                   e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                  a1 f1 R (f fp + 
                    ep mp (h + R)))^2))))/(4 ep^3 f1 fp mp (h + 
          R)^2 (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
          e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)))) + 
  ab e1 ep (-(((ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp + a1 mp R) + 

            ep fp (a1 f f1 R - 
               e1 m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + 
                  R)) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                    ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                   a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2))) (-ep^2 f1 (h +
                R) (ab f f1 fp R - a1 f f1 mp R^2 + 
               ab e1 fp m1 mp (h + R) + 
               e1 m1 mp (2 fp - a1 mp) R (h + R)) - 
            ep fp (a1 f^2 f1^2 R^2 - 
               e1 f f1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) R (h + R) + 
               e1^2 fp m1^2 mp (h + R)^2) + 
            e1 h m1 mp \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                    ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
            f f1 R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                    ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
            e1 m1 mp R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                    ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + 
                    ep mp (h + R)))^2))))/(4 a1 ep fp mp (h + 
            R)^2 (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
            e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)))) + 
     e1 m1 ((1/(
        2 a1 (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
           ep f1 R)))(ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp + a1 mp R) + 
          ep fp (a1 f f1 R - e1 m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R)) + Sqrt[
          ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
               e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
               a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)]) - 
        ep (mp + (1/(
           2 a1 ep (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R)))(a1 ep f f1 fp R - 
             e1 ep fp^2 m1 (h + R) + 
             ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp - 
                a1 mp R) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + 
                    R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + 
                    ep mp (h + R)))^2)))))) - (e1 (ep^2 f1 (h + 
          R) (ab fp + a1 mp R) + 
       ep fp (a1 f f1 R - e1 m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R)) + Sqrt[
       ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
             e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
            e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
            a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)]) (-ep^2 f1 (h + 
          R) (ab f f1 fp R - a1 f f1 mp R^2 + ab e1 fp m1 mp (h + R) +
           e1 m1 mp (2 fp - a1 mp) R (h + R)) - 
       ep fp (a1 f^2 f1^2 R^2 - e1 f f1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) R (h + R) + 
          e1^2 fp m1^2 mp (h + R)^2) + 
       e1 h m1 mp Sqrt[
        ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
              e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
             e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
             a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)] + 
       f f1 R Sqrt[
        ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
              e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
             e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
             a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)] + 
       e1 m1 mp R Sqrt[
        ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
              e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + R) - 
             e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
             a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)]) (ep R (ep mp - (1/(
          2 a1 (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
             ep f1 R)))(ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp + a1 mp R) + 
            ep fp (a1 f f1 R - 
               e1 m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + 
                  R)) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                    ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                   a1 f1 R (f fp + 
                    ep mp (h + R)))^2)))) - ((-ep^2 f1 (h + 
               R) (ab f f1 fp R - a1 f f1 mp R^2 + 
               ab e1 fp m1 mp (h + R) + 
               e1 m1 mp (2 fp - a1 mp) R (h + R)) - 
            ep fp (a1 f^2 f1^2 R^2 - 
               e1 f f1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) R (h + R) + 
               e1^2 fp m1^2 mp (h + R)^2) + 
            e1 h m1 mp \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                    ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
            f f1 R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                    ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
            e1 m1 mp R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                    ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + 
                    ep mp (h + R)))^2))) (-((m1 (a1 ep f f1 fp R - 
                   e1 ep fp^2 m1 (h + R) + 
                   ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp - 
                    a1 mp R) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + 
                    R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2))) (ep^2 f1 (h +
                     R) (ab fp + a1 mp R) + 
                   ep fp (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + 
                    R)) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + 
                    R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + 
                    ep mp (h + R)))^2)))^2 (-ep^2 f1 (h + 
                    R) (ab f f1 fp R - a1 f f1 mp R^2 + 
                    ab e1 fp m1 mp (h + R) + 
                    e1 m1 mp (2 fp - a1 mp) R (h + R)) - 
                   ep fp (a1 f^2 f1^2 R^2 - 
                    e1 f f1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) R (h + R) + 
                    e1^2 fp m1^2 mp (h + R)^2) + 
                   e1 h m1 mp \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + 
                    R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
                   f f1 R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + 
                    R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2)) + 
                   e1 m1 mp R \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + 
                    R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2))) (fp + (1/(
                   2 ep (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                    ep f1 R)))(a1 ep f f1 fp R - 
                    e1 ep fp^2 m1 (h + R) + 
                    ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp - 

                    a1 mp R) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + 
                    R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + 
                    ep mp (h + 
                    R)))^2)))))/(16 a1^2 ep^3 f1 fp^2 mp (h + 
                   R)^4 (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R)^3 (a1 f f1 R - 
                   e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)))) + 
            ep (ep mp + (1/(
               2 a1 (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R)))(a1 ep f f1 fp R - 
                 e1 ep fp^2 m1 (h + R) + 
                 ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp - 
                    a1 mp R) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + 
                    R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 
                    a1 f1 R (f fp + ep mp (h + R)))^2))) - (1/(
               2 a1 (h + R) (e1 fp m1 + 
                  ep f1 R)))(ep^2 f1 (h + R) (ab fp + a1 mp R) + 
                 ep fp (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + 
                    R)) + \[Sqrt](ep^2 (-4 a1 fp mp (h + 
                    R) (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
                    e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)) + (ab ep f1 fp (h + 
                    R) - e1 fp m1 (fp - 2 a1 mp) (h + R) + 

                    a1 f1 R (f fp + 
                    ep mp (h + R)))^2))))))/(2 ep^2 f1 mp (h + 
            R) (a1 f f1 R - 
            e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R)))))/(4 ep^2 fp^2 mp (h + 
       R)^2 (e1 fp m1 + ep f1 R) (a1 f f1 R - 
       e1 m1 (fp - a1 mp) (h + R))))
```

This has just been running continuously. Previously I got an output of 5 solutions.

```
  Eq1solve = Solve[Eq1==0, fp]
```

When I use a numerical solver, this was verified:

```
Pars = {f -> 1, h -> 1, ab -> 0.1, a1 -> 0.1, f1 -> 0.1, e1 -> 0.1, 
   m1 -> 0.1, ep -> 0.1, mp -> 0.01,R -> 1000};
NSolve[{F3 == 0} /. Pars, fp]
Plot[F3 /. Pars, {fp, -1, 5}] 
    #Output
    {{fp -> -0.193087}, {fp -> 0.0123643 - 0.17559 I}, {fp -> 
   0.0123643 + 0.17559 I}, {fp -> 0.167316}, {fp -> 1.1011}}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are running so we can try to replicate the problem.

Comment: Hope this is helpful

Comment: `NSolve[{F3 == 0} /. Pars, fp]`. What is `F3`?